# php curl - posting webkitform data

Tags: php, curl, webkit

I'm trying to send a username and password data into an api, which uses WebKitFormBoundary and the content type needs to be multipart/form-data. This is what the API's input data is..

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryrxt23xc12
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

userhere
------WebKitFormBoundaryrxt23xc12
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

passhere
------WebKitFormBoundaryrxt23xc12--
```

and here's the code I have so far..

```
$form_url = "url.com";

$data_to_post = array();
$data_to_post['username'] = 'usernamehere';
$data_to_post['password'] = 'passwordhere';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, $form_url);

curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, sizeof($data_to_post));

curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_to_post);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

How do I make it work and send the entire text I mentioned at first?

Comment: Hmmm CURLOPT_POST is a binary field, true or false, why are you sending the 'sizeof' here.  Also your POSTFILEDS is formatted wrong for what WebKit is looking for.  You are passing effectively $username=usernamehere&password=passwordhere instead of what they want.

Comment: @Forbs yeah ur right can you help me out how do i make the curlpost a binary field and send what they want?

Comment: Make the above data a big string, and pass that as part of the headers.  Lookup CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS that takes an array but you can create a single entry array out of the string